# react js mui-datatables can't translate labelDisplayedRows text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, material-ui, mui-datatable

I'm using `"mui-datatables": "^4.2.2",` with react js 17 to handle datatable.

I created a liste of options :

```
const options = {
  filter: false,
  download: true,
  sort: false,
  selectableRows: true,
  print: true,
  viewColumns: false,
  searchOpen: false,
  // rowsPerPageOptions: {},
  labelDisplayedRows: ({ from, to, count }) => {
    return "Affichage de " + from + " à " + to + " sur " + count;
  },
  search: true,
  page: 0,
  pageSize: 10,
  // rowsPerPage: 10,
  rowsPerPageOptions: {},
};
```

I want to translate labelDisplayedRows :

```
 labelDisplayedRows: ({ from, to, count }) => {
    return "Affichage de " + from + " à " + to + " sur " + count;
  },

  <MUIDataTable
     title={"Accueil"}
     data={data}
     columns={columns}
     options={options}
   />
```

but it doesn't work.

how can i change the text correctly? thanks

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `customFooter` for this not `labelDisplayedRows`

See [this very basic example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datatables-demo-forked-1kh0k9?file=/src/index.js) just for the proof of concept

And for a more complete example, check [this demo](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/customize-footer/CustomFooter.js) which also includes `MuiTablePagination` in order to have the controls to navigate between pages.